# How can We make a View from Below JSON, We need MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Please see below code and let me know the query.

```
[{"available":true,"platform":"iOS","version":"14.7","uuid":"4B9DEAA2-E2C0-4373-808D-96072BF070C6","cordova":"5.1.1","model":"iPad7,3","manufacturer":"Apple","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-15 15:51:50","installed_app_version":"0.0.1","logout_time":"2021-08-16 07:18:47"},{"available":true,"platform":"Android","version":"10","uuid":"822e2a0a98113125","cordova":"7.1.4","model":"MI 9","manufacturer":"Xiaomi","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-16 06:16:57","installed_app_version":"0.0.1"},{"available":true,"platform":"Android","version":"9","uuid":"32da96d832075053","cordova":"7.1.4","model":"Redmi Note 6 Pro","manufacturer":"Xiaomi","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-16 06:21:55","installed_app_version":"0.0.1"}]
```

Please help me out to make a view from this Json Data

Comment: You have JSON data. Please explain how this is a MySQL question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your json array either stored somewhere in a json column of the table or you have that value somehow in a variabe.

```
SET @temp1 = '[{"available":true,"platform":"iOS","version":"14.7","uuid":"4B9DEAA2-E2C0-4373-808D-96072BF070C6","cordova":"5.1.1","model":"iPad7,3","manufacturer":"Apple","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-15 15:51:50","installed_app_version":"0.0.1","logout_time":"2021-08-16 07:18:47"},{"available":true,"platform":"Android","version":"10","uuid":"822e2a0a98113125","cordova":"7.1.4","model":"MI 9","manufacturer":"Xiaomi","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-16 06:16:57","installed_app_version":"0.0.1"},{"available":true,"platform":"Android","version":"9","uuid":"32da96d832075053","cordova":"7.1.4","model":"Redmi Note 6 Pro","manufacturer":"Xiaomi","isVirtual":false,"serial":"unknown","access_time":"2021-08-16 06:21:55","installed_app_version":"0.0.1"}]';

SELECT
    people.*
FROM
    JSON_TABLE(@temp1,
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (platform VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.platform',
    version1 VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.version') ) people;
```

To be very specific, I have run this code on MySQL 8.0 and hope this will answer your question. Probably this might not work on MySQL 5.7 but give it a try. Checkout my fiddle link below.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f30fecc46522c3b00cddefb3d6550714)